# How to have "onmouseover" highlight in css?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

```
    protected void MasterCust_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#eefef0';");
        }
    }
```

how would I get this into css instead?

```
grid.highlight
{
background-color:Blue;
}
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `hover` selector.

```
grid.highlight:hover
{
    background-color:Blue;
}
```

IE 6, 7 and 8 sometimes have problems with the `hover` selector so, for those, you can use [Whatever:hover](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html).

Comment: IE6 only allows the :hover pseudo selector to be used in anchors (<a>), other than that you are good to go.

Comment: AFAIK, `Whatever:hover` should fix that issue and have it work with any element on IE6. I don't think OP should consider major alternatives (e.g. Javascript) to compensate for IE6 users.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
grid.highlight:hover
{
    background-color: #eefef0;
}
```

Just the add the pseudo-class `:hover` for a mouse-over

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `grid.highlight` select your element:

```
grid.highlight:hover
{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Otherwise, you'll have to modify that selector.